# Lua require from APK

Tags: android, lua, apk

I need to require (load) Lua script files from APKs, on the other hand I wouldn't change the Lua sources.

My first idea was to copy the `loadlib` and `libaux` and using there the `AAsset_*` function but then I've seen that `getc` is used. I assume `fopen` opens the file in text mode and the `AAsset_*` function are only open files in binary mode (I suppose). So, things getting complicated here.

How are you support require from APKs?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers
Implement your own searcher that will load chunk from your assets/vfs in whatever way you'll find convenient, replace second searcher in package.searchers with your own, and probably remove all the rest searchers after second. I.e. only two searcher should be there - first searcher (default) that will look for cached modules, and second searcher will be yours.
Similar functionality available for Lua 5.1: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders